# Mysql Concat two columns while searching with LIKE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a MySQL query where I filter the records based on the search text using LIKE keyword.

For example if the user searches for `Illusion Softwares` where `Illusion` is First name and `Softwares` is last name so the query should search for columns FirstName, LastName and concat both and search.

I have tried this so far but it does not work for `CONCAT`

```
 Select Contacts.*, Contacts.ID as CID from Contacts left join
 website_Data  on Contacts.ID = website_Data.ContactID where
 Contacts.`FirstName` LIKE '%Illusion Softwares%' or 
 Contacts.`LastName` LIKE '%Illusion Softwares%' or
 concat(Contacts.FirstName, ' ', Contacts.LastName) 
 LIKE '%Illusion Softwares%'
 or Contacts.Email LIKE '%Illusion Softwares%' 
 order by Contacts.`Created` DESC
```

What am I missing? Please help me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your query should be like this

```
Select Contacts.*, Contacts.ID as CID 
from Contacts 
left join website_Data 
on Contacts.ID = website_Data.ContactID 
where CONCAT(Contacts.FirstName,' ', Contacts.LastName) LIKE '%Illusion Softwares%' 
order by Contacts.`Created` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,c.ID as CID 
FROM Contacts c
LEFT OUTER JOIN website_Data w ON c.ID=w.ContactID
WHERE c.Email OR CONCAT_WS(' ',c.FirstName,c.LastName) LIKE '%Illusion Softwares%'
ORDER BY c.Created DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also, this worked for me,

```
$this->db->or_like('CONCAT(Contacts.FirstName,' ', Contacts.LastName)',$search);
```

Comment: Use  CONCAT_WS() instead CONCAT()

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT_WS in your query:

```
$this->db->or_like('CONCAT_WS(Contacts.FirstName,' ', Contacts.LastName)',$search);
```