# SQL impossible LIKE statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table like this:

```
ID | REFERENCE | COLOUR | SIZE
---------------------------------
1  | ref1234   | black  | 4
2  | ref1234   | blue   | 12
3  | 1290013ol | orange | us
```

I retrieve a file from a third-party app to make operations in this table (for instance, decrement stock).

The thing is, the info I retrieve to match this table is always formatted like this: REFERENCECOLOURSIZE, i.e ref1234black4 (no underscore or something to dissociate the 3).

I'm using PHP along with MySQL. Is it possible to use a complex SQL LIKE query to match for instance the first line with ref1234black4?

I don't really know how to deal with this, or if it's possible anyway.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to use a regexp to split the code before making the query?

Comment: please give a couple of lines of raw sample data you get as raw input.(dont try to format it yourself)

Comment: @Sal00m MySQL doesn't have any functions to split a string based on regexp.

Comment: @Barmar I know, i said before making the query, so use php to split the reference, colour and size

Comment: @Sal00m It also doesn't look like there's any pattern to it that could be used in the regexp.

Comment: Try to use CONCAT with LIKE, this should helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178000/6445828

Comment: @REJack Why `Like`? It looks like the OP is looking for an exact match.

Comment: Is there a whitelist of colors?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Tschallacka the input is just a simple txt file a retrieve and handle in php, pipe separated (like .csv). There are several information, but just one related to this table. I retrieve the information "ref_merchant" in a simple php var such as `$my_var = 'ref1234black4'`

Comment: @SalmanA they unfortunately have neither colours nor sizes whitelisted. This was my first intent in php :/

Comment: @REJack I'll try now, thanks for the idea!

Comment: The reason why raw input data is to see if there's anything hidden in there. I don't know what you do with the data before it ends up in your var. There might be null spaces in there, something else that's useful to separate data. without seeing raw data, it's hard to see.

Comment: @Tschallacka yes I got your point, sorry if my answer wasn't clear. I looped through pipe exploded data and store the result directly in vars. The raw input (i.e was ref1234black4)  is the same as it is in the end in the var. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not able to split the data in your client application, you can always concatenate the separate columns in your database.
As long as the identifiers are all correct, this should return the row you are looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(reference, colour, size) = 'REFERENCECOLOURSIZE'
```

Comment: Thanks! I used CONCAT along with LIKE such as suggested by @REJack and it does the trick!